# How to estimate the maximum load that my AWS EC 2 instance can handle?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load, performance-testing

Now that I have setup my backend on aws, I want to test that with this setup. At how many requests does the AWS ec2 i/o utilization becomes nearly 100%, so that I can estimate the number of users that can be served with that ec2 instance having my processing back-end.

I found tools like blazemeter, but in blazemeter I am not able to send json of this kind :
[{
   "title" : "demo",
   "posts" : ['one', 'two'],
   "owner" : "aa"
}].
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

When we were ready to deploy one of our first production loads on AWS, we wanted to "size" the system, to understand what kind of max load the system could withstand without breaking.

We checked a few tools (Selenium, CloudBees) and finally selected [Load Impact](https://loadimpact.com/)

The tests are written in [Lua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)), and while we had no experience in it, the language is easy to learn.

One nice feature is that is has an embedded monitoring agent you can install on the instances, and you get very detailed OS level reporting about memory and CPU.

We signed up for a monthly service, and I think we wrapped up all testing within 2 months.

We gained a lot of insight into our platform, and felt more confident about platform stability under load.

Comment: Load Impact is not able to process my url having the ip-address of the aws ec2. It keeps on giving this error : We were unable to successfully analyze this URL. If the problem persists, please try using our Chrome extension or Proxy recorder

Comment: We had no such issue. I would reach out to their support - they were very helpful. We had 4 servers, ELB DB everything.  We got it up to 200 users. Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) tool, the configuration would be as simple as:

1. Add [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to your Test Plan
2. Add [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to the Thread Group
3. Configure it as follows:

   [image: JMeter for API testing]
4. Optionally you can also add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type)

That's it, now you can either amend number of virtual users in Thread Group and test your application from your machine or use BlazeMeter where you will be able to define load pattern using web interface.

Check out [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right) article for more information if needed